# Passing dynamic values to order records in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to sort a record in following way.

1. Arrange records in group (by ID column)
2. Sort the step 1 results by ascending order (by NAME column)

   2.1. If NAME Column having same values, then order by FLAG column value (ascending order)
3. Order the Step 2 results by Order Assist column (I will be passing dynamic value to sort using order assist column)

**My Query:**

```
SELECT IDENTIFIER, CODE, INC_EXC_FLAG,ORDER_ASSIST FROM DUMMY_SORT 
WHERE METHOD_ID = '1'
GROUP BY (IDENTIFIER, CODE, INC_EXC_FLAG,ORDER_ASSIST)
ORDER BY ORDER_ASSIST ASC, CODE ASC, INC_EXC_FLAG ASC
```

**Result of above Query:**

```
ID      NAME    FLAG    ORDER_ASSIST
A_EC     AEC    0         EC1
B_EC_DET BEC    1         EC2
A_NIT    ANIT   0         NIT1
A_NIT    ANIT   1         NIT1
A_NIT    BNIT   0         NIT1
B_NIT_DET BNIT  0         NIT2
B_NIT_DET BNIT  1         NIT2
A_SC      ASC   0         SC1
A_SC      ASC   1         SC1
B_SC_DET  BSC   0         SC2
B_SC_DET  BSC   1         SC2
C_SC_FUN  CSC   0         SC3
D_SC_GRP  DSC   0         SC4
```

But I want to generate the result according to dynamic values of order_assist

**For Example:**

If I am passing dynamic value as "SC" i want to fisrt order the  records SC1,SC2,SC3. Then NIT1,NIT2 . then EC1,EC2.
If I am passing dynamic value as "NITG" i want to fisrt order the  records  NIT1,NIT2  then SC1,SC2,SC3. then EC1,EC2.

**Expected result added when dynamic value is "SC"**

```
ID        NAME    FLAG  ORDER_ ASSIST
A_SC       ASC      0      SC1
A_SC       ASC      1      SC1
B_SC_DET   BSC      0       SC2
B_SC_DET   BSC      1       SC2
C_SC_FUN   CSC      0       SC3
D_SC_GRP   DSC      0        SC4
A_NIT      ANIT     0       NIT1
A_NIT      ANIT     1       NIT1
A_NIT      BNIT     0       NIT1
B_NIT_DET  BNIT     0        NIT2
B_NIT_DET  BNIT     1        NIT2
A_EC       AEC      0       EC1
B_EC_DET   BEC      1       EC2
```

Comment: the rules for ordering are not clear.

Comment: The rules is, My group by query will group the records as i expect, but i want to order the records dynamically like, If my class pass "SC1" to Order_assist column then i want to order the records as SC1,SC2,SC3,SC4,NITG1,NITG2,EC1,EC2. If NIT1 passed to ORDER_ASSIST i want to order as NIT1,NIT2 then SC1,SC2,SC3. then EC1,EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like maybe you're after something like:

```
order by case when p_sort_param = 'SC' and order_assist like 'SC%' then 1
              when p_sort_param = 'SC' and order_assist like 'NIT%' then 2
              when p_sort_param = 'NITG' and order_assist like 'NIT%' then 1
              when p_sort_param = 'NITG' and order_assist like 'SC%' then 2
              else 3
          end,
          order_assist
```

where p_sort_param is the parameter that gets passed in to provide the "dynamic" value. This assumes you're running the query via a stored procedure. If it's a manually run query (eg. in Toad), then add a colon in front of the parameter name to make `:p_sort_param`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand your specific ordering rules, but you should be able to achieve what you want using CASE expressions:

```
order by 
    case order_assist
        when 'SC' then <first thing to order by for SC>
        when 'NITG' then <first thing to order by for NITG>
        ...
        end,
    case order_assist
        when 'SC' then <second thing to order by for SC>
        when 'NITG' then <second thing to order by for NITG>
        ...
        end,
    ... etc.
```

Comment: In the above case, i will not get record order as SC1,SC2,SC3,SC4,NITG1,NITG2,EC1,EC2. My expected result is when SC1 is passed dynamically to ORDER_ASSIST i want to order as SC1,SC2,SC3,SC4,NITG1,NITG2,EC1,EC2. If NIT1 passed to ORDER_ASSIST i want to order as NIT1,NIT2 then SC1,SC2,SC3. then EC1,EC2.